# Airflow worker not understanding file encoding when parsing a file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, airflow

With the following code :

```
import pandas as pd

    filename = r"/path/to/my/file.csv"

    with open(filename) as f:
        data_frame = pd.read_csv(f,
                            usecols=['col1', 'col2'],
                            parse_dates=['DateProd', 'DateStart', 'DateEnd'],
                            header=0,
                            delimiter=';',
                            encoding='latin-1')
        print(data_frame)
```

When this is executed locally, it prints the expected dataframe with proper accentuation.  When executed in an airflow task on a remote worker, it fails with the following error :

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 2581: invalid continuation byte

When looking at the full debug strack trace (sorry, sensitive information, can't fully provide), I see within the stack trace that encoding='latin-1' was definitely specified, and it still fails with the UnicodeDecodeError error.  Anybody noticed a similar issue?  I've been running in circles, trying as many encoding as possible, but nothing seems to work.

I forgot to mention that the file is a remote file on a samba share.  Wether I try to read it directly with smbclient.open() or copy it over locally and then opening it, I get the same result : UnicodeDecodeError.  When I try the same thing locally (both reading directly from the samba share, or copying it over), everything seems fine, and I noticed I don't even need to specify the encoding, it will find it automatically, and accents will be displayed properly.

Another update : It seems that wether the file is read from the samba share or not does not make a difference.  I managed to run the docker image that is used on the remote worker, and I can reproduce this issue with everything hosted locally, wether I open the file before, wether I read it entirely before giving it to pandas, or wether I simply give the filename to read_csv.

The engine does not seem to make a difference either : specifying engine='python' or engine='c' yield the same results.

Another update : It appears that this same issue is also happening with a fresh ubuntu docker image.  I'm guessing there is some locales that need to be installed before it is able to parse them.

Comment: Can you try `open(filename, 'rb')` instead of `open(filename)` ?

Comment: You don't need to open the file at all, pandas handles that for you under the hood, simply do `pd.read_csv(filename, ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out.

On a Windows machine, the encoding seems to be different by default.  I don't even have to specify an encoding for it to work.  Not in the container.  Thus, I need to specify the encoding when opening files in the containers.  The following should work :

```
import pandas as pd

filename = r"/path/to/my/file.csv"

with open(filename, encoding='latin-1') as f:
    data_frame = pd.read_csv(f,
                        usecols=['col1', 'col2'],
                        parse_dates=['DateProd', 'DateStart', 'DateEnd'],
                        header=0,
                        delimiter=';',)
                        # Notice the lack of encoding='latin-1' here.
    print(data_frame)
```

But!  SambaHook essentially returns a pysmbclient's SambaClient.  When you try to open a file with this Sambaclient, there is no way to specify the encoding of the file.  So, locally, on a windows machine, everything seems to work fine.  In a linux container, it fails with the UnicodeDecodeError.  Looking under the hood, I've found that it essentially copies the file over before simply calling open() on the file.

For now, this is my solution : Copy the file over with the SambaClient returned by SambaHook in a temp file, open it with the proper encoding, ask panda to parse it.  I will see what I can do about improving SambaHook and pysmbclient so that others can specify the encoding when opening a file.